# Is something wrong with my Adafruit motor shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

I think something may be wrong with my shield, as I looked at the other forums related to this question and still can not get help.

I know that I can't run it from a 9V source by itself, as the Adafruit website specifically said I can't. So they said to use a LiPo battery or 8 AA batteries. So I tried powering the shield with 8 AA batteries and the light comes on to confirm that.

I then added a 9 volt battery to power the Arduino itself. My motor is a DC motor from RadioShack that can work at 9V, 12V or 18V. I have the motor connected to M2. What am I doing wrong? Here is [the site I am following](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/powering-motors).

Here is [the DC motor](https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-super-speed-9-18vdc-hobby-motor).

Again, if anyone knows what I am doing wrong, that would be very helpful to know. Thank you for your time and effort.

Edit 1:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ); // create motor #2, 64KHz pwm

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
  Serial.println("Motor test!");
  motor.setSpeed(200); // set the speed to 200/255
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("tick");
  motor.run(FORWARD); // turn it on going forward
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("tock");
  motor.run(BACKWARD); // the other way
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("tack");
  motor.run(RELEASE); // stopped
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Please describe what is not working

Comment: The motor is not spinning even though I know the motor is working. I think there was a thread called motor not spinning or something but that thread did not help. So what am I doing wrong that the motor doesn't spin?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how the 8 AA batteries are configured? Are they in series or parallel or some combination? How are you initiating the signal to motor that it should turn? Do you have some code?

Comment: The batteries are in series as they are in a battery holder that I got from radio shack. All battery holders are in series. I will provide the code at edit number 1.

Comment: Does anyone know what is wrong? I have been searching for days.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information yet. So far it could be a) the motor is not getting the signal to rotate, or b) if it is receiving the signal, then the motor can't source enough current from your battery setup. Without a code example we're just guessing.

Comment: That is the code. I gave the code. What are you talking about? Also, the motor is firmly attacked to the shield. I have the right current set up or at least I think I do. I said what it was, I have given the code at edit number 1. What other information do you need? Someone has got to tell me what information or else how am I suppose to give you the information needed?